# I want to remove duplicate from list (without for loop)

Tags: python

Here I have a list

```
a = [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 4, 6]
```

Now I want a following output but without for loop.
Remove all the duplicate from the list.

```
[2, 5, 7, 8, 6]
```

output list contain only single occurrence number

Comment: `set(a)` will yield a non-duplicate result as a set object.

Comment: @swatchai ... and mess up the original order.

Comment: What's the criteria of the output. Does it have to be that exact output? In other words, are you looking to remove the first occurrence when you find the duplicate? Or are you looking to remove the second? Because, without the details you provided, `list(set(your_list))` could be a valid solution. But your question is vague and still missing your own code effort here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and a conditional list comprehension or `filter` in order to maintain the original order:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(a)
clean_a = filter(lambda x: c[x] == 1, a)  # avoids 'for' ;-)
# clean_a = list(filter(lambda x: c[x] == 1, a))  # Python3, if you need a list
# clean_a = [x for x in a if c[a] == 1]  # would be my choice
```

Comment: @efkin A comprehension is not a for loop, just because there is a `for`.

Comment: sorry about that... i thought it was a similar implementation ... i'm removing my down vote. do you know where i can read some specification about it?

Comment: I don't think there is a need to use additional libraries and methods for such a simple task

Comment: @DanielTrugman: Ah, come on. `collections` is part of the Python standard library.

Comment: @DanielTrugman And yet, this is very concise and will outperform all the suggested solutions involving repeated calls to `count()`

Comment: @Matthias, python is all about simplicity... why use such heavy guns for such an easy task?

Comment: @DanielTrugman your solution is `O(n^2)` while this is `O(n)`

Comment: @DanielTrugman that's still not O(N)... You're scanning `a` once to uniqueify, then scanning it N times for the `.count` for however many unique values there are...

Answer (score 3):

Given: `a = [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 4, 6]`

**One liner:**

```
b = [x for x in a if a.count(x) == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple and inefficient implementation.

We use a `while` loop to access every element of `a`. In the loop we check if the current element appears only once in the list. If yes, we add it to a new list.

```
a = [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 4, 6]
index = 0
result = []
while index < len(a):
    if a.count(a[index]) == 1:
        result.append(a[index])
    index += 1

print(result)
```

Comment: Wonder if it's worth bothering to check that `a[index]` isn't in `result` first to avoid the counting again of elements you know are unique... For large `a`s and small amounts of unique values - might be worth it...

Comment: Could be an idea. It's just one extra line of code. On the other hand noone would use this in production. Throw away this strange restraint "without a for loop" and I'm sure you'd find better solutions.

Comment: Yeah could just make the line `if not a[index] in result or a.count(a[index]) == 1` - but yes, in any non-teacher-thought-it-was-a-good-constraint-to-make scenario you'd use Counter or similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
def cleaner(LIST, pos):
    if len(LIST)>pos:
        if LIST[pos] in LIST[pos+1:]:
            LIST.pop(pos)
            # OR
            # LIST.remove(LIST[pos])
            cleaner(LIST, pos)
    else:
        pos+=1
        cleaner(LIST, pos)
    return LIST        


LIST = [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 4, 6]
print(cleaner(LIST, 0))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).